ConstraintLayout in compose multiplatform?
How to use ConstraintLayout in multiplatform compose..
      commonMain.dependencies {
        implementation(compose.runtime)
        implementation(compose.foundation)
        implementation(compose.material)
        implementation(compose.ui)
        implementation(compose.components.resources)
        implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
        implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1")




    }


As of July 2024, Google's official ConstraintLayout() implementation is only for Android, and JetBrains has not created an official Compose Multiplatform port.
However, this GitHub repo contains an independent port of ConstraintLayout().
